# SoftException in Application.cpp:690: Could not execute script *.php

Tags: php, cloudflare

When I enable Cloudflare on my web site I get intermittent and random errors in cPanel log that say:
SoftException in Application.cpp:690: Could not execute script "/.../public_html/index.php"
After doing a lot of research, I can confirm that my file permissions are good, my .htaccess appears good, and I do not use any plug-ins.
My php code has been running without such errors for many years... the issue occurs only when I enable Cloudflare. Where else do you suggest I look for the root cause?

Thanks,
Paul.